# Select duplicate persons with duplicate memberships

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/93065/2) with schema and my intial attempt.

```
CREATE TABLE person
    ([firstname] varchar(10), [surname] varchar(10), [dob] date, [personid] int);

INSERT INTO person
    ([firstname], [surname], [dob] ,[personid])
VALUES
    ('Alice', 'AA', '1/1/1990', 1),
    ('Alice', 'AA', '1/1/1990', 2),
    ('Bob'  , 'BB', '1/1/1990', 3),
    ('Carol', 'CC', '1/1/1990', 4),
    ('Alice', 'AA', '1/1/1990', 5),
    ('Kate' , 'KK', '1/1/1990', 6),
    ('Kate' , 'KK', '1/1/1990', 7)

;

CREATE TABLE person_membership
    ([personid] int, [personstatus] varchar(1), [memberid] int);

INSERT INTO person_membership
    ([personid], [personstatus], [memberid])
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 10),
    (2, 'A', 20),
    (3, 'A', 30),
    (3, 'A', 40),
    (4, 'A', 50),
    (4, 'A', 60),
    (5, 'T', 70),
    (6, 'A', 80),
    (7, 'A', 90);

CREATE TABLE membership
    ([membershipid] int, [memstatus] varchar(1));

INSERT INTO membership
    ([membershipid], [memstatus])
VALUES
    (10, 'A'),
    (20, 'A'),
    (30, 'A'),
    (40, 'A'),
    (50, 'T'),
    (60, 'A'),
    (70, 'A'),
    (80, 'A'),
    (90, 'T');
```

There are three tables (as per the fiddle above).  `Person` table contains duplicates, same people entered more than once, for the purpose of this exercise we assume that a combination of the first name, surname and DoB is enough to uniquely identify a person.

I am trying to build a query which will show duplicates of people (first name+surname+Dob) with two or more active entries in the `Person` table (`person_membership.person_status=A`) AND two or more active memberships (`membership.mestatus=A`).

Using the example from SQL Fiddle, the result of the query should be just Alice (two active person IDs, two active membership IDs).
[image]

I think I'm making progress with the following effort but it looks rather cumbersome and I need to remove Katie from the final result - she doesn't have a duplicate membership.

```
SELECT q.firstname, q.surname, q.dob, p1.personid, m.membershipid 
FROM
(SELECT
  p.firstname,p.surname,p.dob, count(*) as cnt
FROM
  person p
GROUP BY
  p.firstname,p.surname,p.dob
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) as q
INNER JOIN person p1 ON q.firstname=p1.firstname AND q.surname=p1.surname AND q.dob=p1.dob
INNER JOIN person_membership pm ON p1.personid=pm.personid
INNER JOIN membership m ON pm.memberid = m.membershipid
WHERE pm.personstatus = 'A' AND m.memstatus = 'A'
```

Comment: sorry, but can you post expected output ?

Comment: As it says in the question - "The result of the query should be just Alice (two active person IDs, two active membership IDs)."

Comment: @MichalRosa So basically only the name "Alice"? Your comment in the answer below seems to indicate that you also want the IDs in some form.

Comment: I would like to see the output exactly as specified in the question firstname, surname, dob, personid, memberid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server windows function will be handy for this scenario. The following will give you the expected output.

```
SELECT firstname,surname,dob,personid,memberid
from(
SELECT firstname,surname,dob,p.personid,memberid
,Rank() over(partition by p.firstname,p.surname,p.dob order by p.personid) rnasc
,Rank() over(partition by p.firstname,p.surname,p.dob order by p.personid desc) rndesc
FROM [StagingGRG].[dbo].[person] p
INNER JOIN person_membership pm ON p.personid=pm.personid
INNER JOIN membership m ON pm.memberid = m.membershipid
where personstatus='A' and memstatus='A')a
where a.rnasc+rndesc>2
```

Comment: Thank you.  Needed a couple of typos fixed, I assume left for me as an excercise to see if I'm paying attention.  Very clever.  After five minutes of staring at the monitor I have worked out how it works.  Will save it as a template for my future battles with SQL.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `Group by` and `Having` clause to return duplicate items only-

```
SELECT
  person.firstname,person.surname,person.dob
FROM
  person, person_membership, membership
WHERE
  person.personid=person_membership.personid AND person_membership.memberid = membership.membershipid
AND
  person_membership.personstatus = 'A' AND membership.memstatus = 'A'
GROUP BY
  person.firstname,person.surname,person.dob
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: Always preferable to use ANSI JOIN syntax. It is recommended.

Comment: Your solution does not show person.personid, membership.membershipid information for Alice and includes Bob who should not be there (he has a single entry in the person table) so sadly it's not what I am looking for.